# How to manage memory returned from function in C

Tags: c, memory, return, substring, free

I want to make a tokenization sub-program which will work like this :

- Read user input
- Find tokens
- Use a substring function to get each token
- Store each token in a struct

The idea was simple ( i think ) but I came up with a difficult problem. When making the substring function, I realized that it was a memory leak hole. The only way i can think of making a substring function is this :

```
    char* sub = ( char* ) malloc ( ( some_length + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    for ( i = start_index ; i < some_length ; i++ )
    {
         sub[ i - start_index ] = source_string[i];
    }

    sub[ some_length ] = '\0'

    return sub;
```

But the problem is that when using the substring function, i won't have the ability to free that memory afterwards.

```
    // Example usage

    TokenStruct* MyToken = CreateToken( substring( input , start , length ) );
```

Some may suggest that i should free memory inside the CreateToken function but this seems like a VERY bad idea to me because it will make CreateToken's code very dependent on the substring function. Also, the substring function might be used in many other functions.

I had an idea of keeping a table of pointers and free them before terminating the program but seems kind of sketchy...

What do you think guys? What is the best way to deal with this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let `TokenStruct` store the token by reference (`char *`). And define `substring()` as a source/creator, which's result needs to be deleted, like `strdup()` for example.

Comment: You may want to consider using [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) as an indirect means of solving your problem. And `#include <string.h>` and use `strncpy()` instead of your `for`-loop.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.  And `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: @alk This would be a nice idea but what if i want initialize TokenStruct with a variable not created by substring function?

Comment: @CarlNorum 1) Just a habit 2) Just a habit too :P

Comment: @Carl Norum `char` is not `1` by C language spec. Sizes of basic types are only defined relative to each other.

Comment: @meaning-matters, that's wrong.  `sizeof(char)` is `1`.  Always.  From the spec: "(`sizeof`), when applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is `1`."

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou: Use `strdup()` to make a copy of it.

Comment: @meaning-matters, no you're not right when talking about the language specification.  I quoted it, even.

Comment: Unrelated, Γιωρος, (I'm sure there are some accents necessary, but I don't know which), it hurts me when people use 'w' to mimic 'ω', those are entirely unrelated letters. Since nowadays almost everything can display glyphs beyond the Latin alphabet, can you consider using Greek letters for your name?

Comment: @Carl Norum In my days of using C it was still defined to be no larger than `short` as can be read [here](http://c.comsci.us/etymology/type/char.html). From which version of the spec are you quoting?

Comment: @meaning-matters, that site must be lying to you.  My quotation is from C99, but it holds for older standards, and even for (most? all?) pre-standardized C.  There are plenty of questions & answers on Stack Overflow if you care to read more.

Comment: @Carl Norum I've learned something today, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  On further reading, there is a lot of suspcicious (read: wrong) information at that link.  I'd write that site off as "not reliable."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem in C and other languages of the same type. There are basically three solutions to this:

1. Either do the call separately and then free the memory afterwards.
2. Keep the pointer in the object (`MyToken` in your case), and free the string when you free the object.
3. Use an array, and pass it in (together with a maximum length) to the function.

Since the created pointer have to be "live" for the life of your object (`MyToken`) anyway, then I suggest method number two.

Comment: I just commented above about your second suggestion that this will prevent me from initializing MyToken with a variable that i want to change afterwards. Not all TokenStructs will be initialized using substring. Do you think that i should give away that "freedom" i described above or do something else?

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou For those occasions where you don't initialize the structure with `substring` then you can use e.g. `strdup`, and you know that the pointer in the structure is always allocated on the heap.

Comment: @JoachimPilebord I fail to understand how strdup will help me. A quick search on google showed me that it is used to duplicate a string... can you please explain?

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou The `Strdup` allocates memory for the duplicate string on the heap, just like `malloc`. If the string is always allocated on the heap, then you know you can always `free` it then you `free` the object.

Comment: I have been programming for many hours and my mind is kind of blurred so i can't understand "where" in the program shall i use strdup?

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou Whenever you create a new token structure, e.g. `CreateToken(strdup(someStringPointer))`. Of course you don't do it if you already allocate memory for the string, as in the case of your `substring` function.